# Can not use group as class attribute name in Entity Framework select query

Tags: entity-framework, linq, .net-core

I am working on .Net Core 2.1 and Entity Framework. I wrote a query to select some data from multiple tables into new object list and one of the attribute name of this object is "group".But when assigning a value to "group" attribute it gives me an error  "The name 'group' does not exist in the current context".
When I changed the name as "groups" or sth else no error left. But I have to use "group" as an attribute name. How can I solve this?

```
var itemsList = (from K in ctx.Card
                 join M in ctx.Product on K.Code equals M.Code
                 join U in ctx.Man on K.Code equals U.Code 
                 select new Item
                            {
                                id = K.CardId,
                                ...
                                group = U.GroupId
                            }).ToList();
```

Comment: Please post what Item class is?

Comment: May be it is because `group` is reserved keyword?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`group` is reserved in this context and if you still want to use the name, return a list of `dynamic` object the create a list of `item` from it.

See below.

```js
List<Item> itemsList = (from K in ctx.Card
                 join M in ctx.Product on K.Code equals M.Code
                 join U in ctx.Man on K.Code equals U.Code 
                 select new
                            {
                                id = K.CardId,
                                ...
                                groupId = U.GroupId
                            }).ToList().Select(x=> new Item {
                              id= x.id,
                              group = x.groupId
                            ......                            
                            }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you Alen, I used your way to solve the problem.